# Does Continuous diffentiablity imply Lipschitz continuity in Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators, nonlinear-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and  $f:[0,\tau]\times X\to X$ is a continuously difference from $[0,\tau]\times X$ into X, then $f$ is continuous in t (first variable) and Lipschitz continuous in u (second variable) uniformly in $t$ on $[0;\tau]$. First part is clear. How do I prove second part? I got this question while studying the book '' Semigroups of linear operators and applications to partial differential equation'' by ''A pazy''.

Comment: Should it be locally Lipschitz continuous in u? Look at $X=\mathbb{R}$, $f(t,u)=u^2$ which is clearly $C^1$ but not Lipschitz on the whole of $X$.

Comment: It is written in the book Lipschitz continuous in the proof of the Theorem 1.5 (page 187). @OlivierMoschetta

Answer (score 0):

We can show that $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous on $u$ (uniformly in $t$), which means the following. For every $u\in X$, there is a neighborhood $N$ of $u$ and a constant $C$ such that
$$||f(t,v)-f(t,u)||_X\leq C ||v-u||_X$$
for every $v\in N$ and $t\in [0,\tau]$.

Let $t\in [0,\tau]$ and $u\in X$ be fixed. Since $f$ is differentiable you may use the mean value theorem and get
$$||f(t,v)-f(t,u)||_X\leq ||Df_X(t,\xi)\cdot(v-u)||_X$$
where $Df_X$ is the "partial" derivative in the $X$ direction and $\xi$ lies on the line segment between $u$ and $v$ in $X$.

Now $f$ is continuously differentiable so there's a neighborhood $N$ of $u$ in $X$ where 
$$||Df_X(t,\xi)||\leq ||Df_X(t,u)||+1$$
in the operator norm. This gives
$$||f(t,v)-f(t,u)||_X\leq \big(||Df_X(t,u)||+1\big) ||v-u||_X$$
when $v\in N$. By compactness of $[0,\tau]$ we can get
$$||f(t,v)-f(t,u)||_X\leq C||v-u||_X$$
where $C$ only depends on $u$, which is what we wanted to prove.